# Query two multivalued fields in solr

Tags: java, apache, solr

I have one question about solr query that it have two multivalued fields.
Fllow it is part of schema:

```
<field name="attribute" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="locale" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

It read data from a xml:

```
  <docs>
    <doc>
        <id>01000</id>
        <name>product1</name>
        <price>102.5</price>        
        <attributes name="description">
          <str attribute="this is english description" locale="en_US" />
          <str attribute="this is chinese description" locale="zh_CN" />
        </attributes>
    </doc>
  </docs>
```

The issues is that query condition either "q=attribute:english AND locale:en_US" or "q=attribute:english AND locale:zh_CN" can return this doc.

I hope only when condition is  "q=attribute:english AND locale:en_US" or "q=attribute:chinese AND locale:zh_CN" that can return the doc ,how can i do it?

Thank you!

Comment: I don´t think you can do this with multivalued fields. I suppose you need to seperate the fields for your issue

Answer (score 1):

The option that Christian Lendel suggested would work, the other option would be joining *attribute* and *locale* options and index it as one string: "en_US this is english description".
Then you can query is like that:

```
q=attribute:(english en_US)
```

Solution might be even simpler or more complex, depends what do you want to achieve.